# can't run example, error '-Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i'm trying to replicate wordcount example from cloudera [website](https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.0/developing-spark-applications/topics/spark-streaming-example.html)

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf 
"spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false" --jars 
 SPARK_HOME/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.6.jar 
 cloudera_analyze.py zookeeper_server:2181 transaction
```

But it gives me this error:

```
C:\openjdk\jdk8025209hotspot\bin\java -cp "C:\spark246hadoop27/conf\;C:\spark246hadoop27\jars\*" 
-Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf

"spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false" --jars 
SPARK_HOME/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.6.jar cloudera_analyze.py zookeeper_server:2181 transaction
```

what could be the reason?

Comment: In my case with spark 3.0.0, it is not working in the bash but the cmd works.

Comment: @Lamanus, hmm could u elaborate on this?

Comment: I have used windows terminal with git-bash and the spark-submit or spark-shell didn't work. Only with the windows cmd, the commands are working correctly. Just in case.

Comment: @Lamanus, yep, thx let me try

Comment: Did you use CDH 7.2.0 to submit this example?

Comment: @HosseinTorabi, no i don't have cdh installed.. i hoped it would work for any spark

Comment: That's the point. The spark version on CDH 7.2.0 is 2.4.5. and many things have been changed through this version

Comment: @HosseinTorabi, it turns out i have working code , but can't run it cuz of stupid spark  or spark-submit...

Comment: @HosseinTorabi, i can't test my code... lol

Comment: Just read the spark docs and examples! you can find  proper examples in this path: $SPARK_HOME/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming